# Probability of two subsets intersect with N elements

Tags: probability

I would like to determine the probability of two subsets A and B intersect with N elements. Could you please help me?

1) I have a universal set W with 1 million finite elements. The two subsets A and B are part of W.  Each has 1 thousand (1000) elements. What is the probability that A and B intersect with fifty (50) elements?

2) can i approximate the factorial computation with a logarithmic formula?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not have the skills to solve this problem. It would not help if I went into false demonstrations. Other posters have been asking the same question in complex ways. Simple question, simple answer will make it useful for everyone.

Comment: It is still best you at the very, very least tell us what you don't understand about the question. Or which concept you are having trouble with. Else you may post this as a discussion or as a chat? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take one element in $B$.  What is the chance it is also in $A$?  Now use the binomial distribution to get the chance $N$ elements of $B$ are also in $A$.  You can certainly use Stirling's approximation for the factorials.  It is very accurate.

Comment: thank you. it was useful. When "W" is the full set, "A" and "B" the two subsets that intersect with "C" elements. The probability of having "C" elements are  A!/(A-C)! * (W-C)!/W! * B!/(B-C)! * (W-C)! / W! .  In a computerized numerical method approximated with Stirling :  Ln(X!) = X*Ln(X) - X +1/2*Ln(2*pi*X).   Following your comment, I implement this in a SQL script to compute kpis. It works well.